# Custom underlines

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, underline

Does anyone know how it is possible to create custom underlines where the text goes onto two lines?

At present I have the following:

```
<h1 class="title" id="page-title">Title goes here</h1>

h1 {
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
line-height: 1.4em;
background-image: url(../img/underline.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: left bottom;
}
```

Problem is when the line becomes longer and wraps, you get only one underline.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dqUc/)

Looking for a solution that works back to IE8

Comment: im not entirely certain i understand what you want but im guessing something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/2dqUc/3/

Comment: Have you read this : http://alistapart.com/article/customunderlines ?

Comment: The code does not apply underlining; instead, it simulates (or fakes) underlining using a repeating bakcground image

Answer (score 0):

The trick used in the code uses a background images that repeats in x direction and is placed at the bottom of the element. Consequently, for any block-like rendering (including inline block) of an element, the “underline” appears at the bottom of the block only.

To make the trick work, in some sense, for multi-line content, you need to make the element an inline element:

```
h1 { display: inline; }
```

You will then need to create any line breaks and vertical spacing using methods like wrapping the `h1` element in a `div` container and setting vertical margins on it.